# How to raise two windows in one Alt + Tab?

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, application-switcher

I'd like to have two (or more) windows (let's assume they are split 50/50) and attach them so that I can, use one <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to get to both.

For example: Having Chrome and Terminal together. Is this possible?
Edit: I wanted to raise and lower more than one window simultaneously.

Comment: Alt+Tab is a task switcher.  Chrome and Terminal are two different tasks, so it is impossible for Alt+Tab to select them together.  Plus, how could you click on both windows or tasks at the same time?

Comment: I want to bring more than one application at the top in one step.

Comment: I am having a hard time figuring out what you are trying to do.  You cannot have more than one application on top at a time.  You cannot select a terminal window with your mouse and select Chrome at the same time so that they are both on top.  It is impossible to type in both windows at the same time.  You can send text from one terminal window to another at the same time, but you are still only typing in one at a time.  So, there can only be one application at the top or that has the focus at a time.  There is no way around this that I am aware of.

Comment: @Terrance I think OP wants to treat two snapped (to left/right edges) windows as a single entity so that they get raised/lowered simultaneously. Incidentally this "feature" was introduced in GNOME 3.26, but removed from later versions after most users found this problematic. I still have this feature in my 17.10 installation. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/990688/480481) for details.

Comment: @pomsky I have given up assuming things about what OP wants.  They stated to me that they wanted them at the top, well, that is what at the top means.  If OP wants something different, let them change the question then.

Comment: Window Tiling https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-windows-tiled.html is not bringing applications to the top.  There can be only 1 application at the top at a time even if the applications are sitting side by side.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing language. I wanted to raise/lower windows only. Thanks @Terrance for explaining it. Edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Terrance said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045310/how-to-raise-two-windows-in-one-alt-tab#comment1704640_1045310), the idea of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is to switch between applications.

Theoretically, you could create some solution and add a key binding. The catch is, how does the app know how to address the individual window sets? So, I suggest using WORKSPACES! They are available in most window managers and desktop environments. If you place 2 windows on one workspace and 2 on another workspace, switching between workspaces does the trick!