# Pair side-by-side windows in GNOME 3

Tags: 18.04, window, gnome-shell, snap-windows

This one is hard to explain.

So basically, when I have two windows in GNOME 3 and make them side by side, so every window fits to one half of the screen, the behavior is not like I experienced it in the past and actually I miss it. The thing that is missing:
When I have the situation described above, but then have another window in focus, I was able to select (using the "Activities" menu) one of the two windows that were side-by-side to each other, and then magically the other-half-window would also come to front. They were kind of **paired**.

I don't know exactly when, but this *"pairing behavior" vanished* somehow and I would like to restore it.

*Something about my system:*
I use GNOME 3 since Ubuntu 17.10 and am now using Ubuntu 18.04. I did not modify it much, except that I use the Settings of Dash to Dock to modify the settings of the Ubuntu dock (The extension is disabled but it seems they still share the configs).

The changed settings include the separation of workspaces (meaning that I can i.e. click on the Firefox logo and instead of changing the workspace, it opens a new Firefox window). It's the only setting that looks related to me, but disabling it doesn't help. And actually the separation is a feature I really want to have. I also used it ever since, when everything was working as I expected. It may be possible that in the past I used the gnome tweak tool to configure it manually, so what I expect may not be the default behavior. I couldn't find anything, and I can't remember setting it up myself.

Comment: I am not sure that the pairing was ever featured in gnome shell itself: the half tiling, where two half tiled windows can be resized together, is only a very recent build-in feature of gnome shell, I believe only since 3.26. Perhaps you should explore ShellTile, that supports this "pairing", quarter tiling and more. Hopefully, more of such features will make it into native Gnome Shell.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll accept it if you make it possible ;) Uh this removal is really strange. I am able to resize two windows together, so their size is dependend on each other, but they do not behave together in any way? Whats the point of skaling them together, then. Feels really wrong/unfinished to me. They should have made this an option.

Comment: There's a new GNOME extension now which claims to do that. Please check the update to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The feature](https://askubuntu.com/questions/970956/gnome-3-26-clicking-one-window-brings-another-in-the-foreground-ubuntu-17-10) you're looking for was actually introduced in GNOME 3.26 (Ubuntu 17.10 came with GNOME 3.26). With GNOME 3.26 you can raise both the snapped windows by raising one of them.

But unfortunately after many complaints against this feature, developers [decided to drop it completely from GNOME 3.28](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=788644#c27), the one in Ubuntu 18.04.

---

**Update:**
However, there is a GNOME shell extension called "[Tandem Raise](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1506/tandem-raise/)" which lets you

> Raise pairs of tiled windows in tandem.

Refer to this to learn about installing and configuring GNOME shell extensions: [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530)

Comment: I there a way to reactivate this feature on Ubuntu 18.04, via a feature flag, or something?

Comment: @DorianMarchal There's a new GNOME extension now which claims to do that. Please check the update to my answer.